# How can i Increase Max_file_upload_size in CPanel using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I am using VPS hosting in that i have CPanel login details ,i was installed wordpress and i am trying import some posts that i have exported from last website.But i am getting the error like Max_file_Upload_size is more than 2M.How can i change the max file upload size .
I was try to add php.ini file to my root folder but i didn't get any change and aslo add php.ini into wp-admin folder also,but i didn't able to import the files.In my Cpanel i didn't find any php.ini files.i am trying in google also but i didn't get answer for me help me....

Comment: put this code in your index file ini_set("upload_max_filesize","300M");

Comment: in index.php where to add that line at the starting line or where?? i am little bit poor about php coding tell me bro...

Comment: you can put it just after the opening php tags in wordpress main index.php <?php ini_set("upload_max_filesize","300M");

Comment: ok i will try and let u know bro

Comment: No problem , Take your time .. :)

Comment: can you please share your code.
what you write and where?

Comment: Too many answers to this question are very wrong. Why? First you have to know what the root of the problem. To do this, you would need to know which values you have in your php. Or a WP plugin, or by creating a single file, with <? Php phpinfo (); and watching her from the browser will know: Where is the php.ini. If your server allows the use of custom php.ini. Some of the answers may be good for you, but I could not. To treat porblemas not enough to "try things". It is analaizar problems. After the solcuiones are sought. Here there are many "professional answering"

Comment: [The Answer is worked well on this link. Appreciate the easy solution. I had to try all other option but they failed only contributor of this answer was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38350549/14244272)

Answer (score 4):

You should just try adding this to the **2nd line** of your **wp-config.php** file.

This line handles your **upload max filesize size** **and** your **php memory.**

```
// this will change your max file size upload AND your php memory
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
```

More info can be seen here regarding this code from the WP Codex (2/3 down the page):

[WP Memory Limit - WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

Comment: This is also not working for me..can u tell me any other solution

Answer (score 3):

Add below line on the top of wordpress main index.php :

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads', 100);
```

Comment: Where to add this line bro...!

Comment: in index.php at first line i need to write this or where to wright this line

Comment: but i am asking max-file-upload-size to increase

Comment: try: ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '8M');

Comment: ini_set use for modify php.ini attribute.
so  ini_set("upload_max_filesize","300M"); increase your max file upload size to 300MB.
you can put it just after the opening php tags in index.php
<?php  
ini_set("upload_max_filesize","300M");
for more information please go through 
http://in2.php.net/ini_set

Comment: this file where to add theme index file or wordpress index file ..can u tell me

Comment: @krishna : in wordpress index.php

Answer (score 2):

The default upload file size for WordPress is 2 MB, which is a problem if you want to upload a large media files. If you get this error, “The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini”, follow these steps:

1. Locate the php.ini file inside the wp-admin directory (if you can’t find this file see notes below)
2. Find this line in the php.ini file “upload_max_filesize = 2M” and replace it with a higher value (e.g.  “upload_max_filesize = 64M”)
3. You may also want to increase your max post size.  Look for this line in your php.ini file “post_max_size” and increase it as well.
4. Save the changes to the file inside your wp-admin directory.
5. Try the upload again
6. If you still have issues, look for this file in your root directory and make the same changes.

If you don’t have a php.ini file in your directory, you can usually generate one from the control panels of your host.

> You can download php.ini file from [here](http://wptheming.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/php.ini).

```
Alternate way using
```

**htaccess**

Add this code in htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

You can increase the file upload limit according to your requirement.

Comment: I don't have option to generate a php.ini file from CPanel.I didn't fine that option bro...can u tell me..

Comment: try using htaccess if you didn't then i will send you link.

Comment: if i change the htaccess file,if edit htaccess file there is nothing will be happend to my entire website right..if there is a chance to occur any problem by editing htaccess file then tell me bro..

Comment: No dear it only increase upload limit for file.Nothing else will happened with this code.check my answer with edits.i put link to `php.ini` file.

Comment: that file i need to add in wp-admin directory or main root of wordpress

Comment: put this file inside `wp-admin` directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44839/discussion-between-krishna-and-mahmood-rehman)

Answer (score 1):

As you say,  you only have access to cpanel, then go to "file manager" in cpanel and then follow Mahmood Rehman's steps.

You can also configure a FTP account and use ftp app like filezilla for downloading and uploading files direclty to the server, and also to edit php.ini and other files.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to point the .htaccess to your custom PHP ini file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /public_html/php.ini
</IfModule>
```

and the write your php.ini files

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

Answer (score 1):

"Error : The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini." Solved by uploading my theme manually. I was also facing the same problem while uploading wordpress theme, My theme is of 3.2MB in size. I searched for following line in wp-config.php file,

// this will change your max file size upload AND your php memory
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );

But it was not found. so I tried another approach, I Log into cpanel went into the directory where wordpress is install then /wp-content/themes, choose upload option and upload my theme and it get installed. :D

Answer (score 1):

Select PHP Version.
Switch to PHP Options
upload_max_filesize 128MB

Answer (score 0):

Create php.ini file and paste below code and upload in public_html its working fine for me.

```
[PHP]
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 750M
upload_max_filesize=750M
max_execution_time=5000
```