# A simple guide to edit php.ini file

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

Like many I have gotten stuck with Wordpress 2mb upload limit, I've done the research and it seems I need to change the `php.ini` file. I normally just use Cpanel for everything however for some reason, `php.ini` file is not accessible using Cpanel, I have full rights/access etc.. to server.

So the question, how do I access the `php.ini` file?

I note that the line of code to do this is probably very simple, but given I have no idea what to do with a line of code, it's ultimately useless to me, so please an idiots guide would be really useful.

---

It appears I am not the only one with this issue - [How can i Increase Max_file_upload_size in CPanel using wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012144/how-can-i-increase-max-file-upload-size-in-cpanel-using-wordpress?rq=1)

All we want to do is increase the upload_max_filesize from 2M - there have been many suggestions using wp-config or index.php - but none of these seem to work.

It appears the only way to do this is to change the php.ini file, however this is only available to those who can connect using ssh, which doesn't work for me despite many hours of typing things into a terminal (I have the rights, just don't know what to do and can't find a step by step explanation online which works)

Does anyone else have any ideas ??

Comment: If you run `phpinfo()` - you'll be able to see which ini files are in use and also where they are located on the server.

Comment: Also - if you're not 100% sure what you're actually doing - I wouldn't recommend tampering with **any** `ini` files. You will be able to very easily mess up your entire PHP installation.

Comment: Google: "php.ini explanation" - just click through the results.

Comment: thanks for you help both, Lix - I tried opening up a terminal (mac OS) and typed "phpinfo()", but it just went blank at me :(

Answer (score 1):

You can install [PHP.ini Manager](http://applications.cpanel.net/php-ini-manager/) plugin for cPanel. Check if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks chiragswadia, looks perfect however I tried following the instructions online and fall down at the phrase 'open an ssh session'

Answer (score 0):

You could just try adding this to the **2nd line** of your WP Config file.

This line handles your **upload max filesize**  size **and** your **php memory**.

```
// this will change your max file size upload AND your php memory
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
```

More info can be seen here regarding this code from the WP Codex (2/3 down the page):

[WP Memory Limit - WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)

EDIT:

You can also you .htaccess file if your host/ini file allows you too.

```
 php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
```

Comment: While this is helpful, it doesn't answer the question at all which was asking about ini files...

Comment: Depending on your hosting type, you may not be able to edit the php.ini file.

Some hosts do not allow you too. If you have access to the server root you should be able to copy the root php.ini file and recreate in the root of your directory. Otherwise you will have to contact your hosting provider and request the amends.

Comment: Note that I'm not the OP here :) Just a friendly commenter... My point is that suggesting how to increase the memory_limit (which is not `upload_max_filesize` nor `post_max_size` BTW) is irrelevant in the OP's search for the `php.ini` file.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you where not the OP.

That line above manages both in WordPress which is why I stated it. 99% of the time WordPress can manage it without having to try find and modify the the php.ini file for the hosting account. It is also a lot safer. 

But this is just my view on the matter. :-)

Comment: Hey guys, again thanks, I think you are both right, being able to change the php.ini file should probably be left to those who can at least connect to their server using ssh (I have the facility to connect  but it just doesn't work !) All I want to do is upload some graphics to WP that is >2MB, so it probably is 'upload_max_filesize' I need to adapt - how do I do this ?

Comment: are you still wanting to use the php.ini file? If NOT then you can use my solution from above.

Just change the number 64 to the size you want E.g 8, 16,32, 64, 128, 256 MB this will increase your PHP memory useage AND your UPLOAD MAX FILE SIZE UPLOAD with one line of code.

Else contact your provider to change your upload_max_filesize in the php.ini

Also you can use your .htaccess file to do the same if you host allows you to: php_value upload_max_filesize 64M

Comment: DLaverick - it is very much your suggestion that I would like to use, unfortunately it doesn't work. I have tried adding "php_value upload_max_filesize 64M" both into .htaccess file and the wp-config file, both times it lead to the WP site no longer functioning :(

Comment: It is this bit that you want in the wp-config file: // this will change your max file size upload AND your php memory
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );   place it at line 2 of your config file.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help, I tried your suggestion and it has changed something - now when I 'add new' media file, it still says the limit is 2M but it doesn't reject the file. Instead now wordpress just hangs for a while, then returns 'Error saving media attachment' - so still no joy !

Comment: in your wp-config.php file, turn on wp-debug by changing the false to true then refresh your media page and try again. It will give you an error/warning to help you debug.